# Use Git repository hosted on S3 instead of Github/Stash in ansible-pull command

Tags: git, amazon-s3, ansible, jgit, ansible-pull

The ansible-pull command looks like this:

`ansible-pull common.yml -C develop -U $REPO -fi localhost`

If I use `REPO="ssh://git@github.com/xyz/xyz.git"`, it works fine.

But if I use `REPO="amazon-s3://.jgit@xyz-bucket/xyz/xyz.git"`, it isn't working obviously as `amazon-s3` isn't a protocol and only `jgit` recognizes it.

For reference, I am using [this guide](https://metamug.com/article/jgit-host-git-repository-on-s3.html) to create a git repository on S3.

Any hacks or solutions are welcome.

Comment: I am not sure if this might help but with ansible pull you can use -m (Repository module name, which ansible will use to check out the repo. Choices are (‘git’, ‘subversion’, ‘hg’, ‘bzr’). Default is git.) See: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-pull.html. Maybe it would be possible to use jgit here after you installed it on your machine?

Comment: `jgit` is installed on my machine but when I run ```ansible-pull common.yml -C develop -m jgit -U $REPO -fi localhost```, it gives me this error: ```ERROR! Unsupported repo module jgit, choices are git```

Answer (score 0):

By default, most tools work with the standard C command-line version of Git (that is, the `git` binary) and not JGit (the `jgit` binary).  It sounds like you have a plugin or other functionality in JGit that allows you to use the `amazon-s3` scheme, but you don't have a generic protocol helper for Git that allows you to do the same thing.

You have two choices here: either symlink `jgit` to `git` somewhere in your PATH, or find and install a suitable protocol helper for Git.  Assuming you have a directory called `bin` in your home directory in your PATH, run `ln -s $(which jgit) ~/bin/git`.  Then, when you (or Ansible) invoke the `git` program, you'll really be using `jgit`, which will cause things to work.

Having said that, the documentation you linked to states that JGit doesn't support the `pull` subcommand; if so, and if `ansible-pull` uses that subcommand, then what you want to do isn't possible with the commands above and you'll need to find and install an equivalent protocol helper for S3 for regular Git.